# MySQL: INSERT ... IF COUNT <= INVENTORY ELSE DONOTHING

Tags: mysql, if-statement, insert

I have a warehouse system where you can insert or remove products with a barcode and a count number. Now I want to check first if there are enough products in the inventory before executing the transaction. So something like: IF enough products in inventory THEN INSERT transaction ELSE donothing (or show error)

I tried this code:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 7 <= (SELECT i.count FROM inventory i WHERE barcode = '123')
THEN 
    INSERT INTO transactions 
           (companyid,barcode,fromlocation,tolocation,count) 
    VALUES (1,'123','Warehouse','Factory',7)
END
```

But it says:

```
1. Unexpected keyword. (near "INTO" at position 88)
2. Unexpected end of CASE expression (near " " at position 87)
3. Unrecognized keyword. (near "END" at position 198)
```

So obviously this is the wrong syntax, but i searched everywhere and could not find an if statement which provides this scenario.

Can somebody tell me how to write the correct if statement?

I know that I could make a select statement first, compare the values and just then insert the transaction (with a MySQL beginTransaction and commit), but I am pretty sure that there has to be another way. (When I talk about transaction I don't talk about the transaction from MySQL but about a transaction from my database)

Thank you

Comment: If you are going to use `i.count` dont you need to give the `inventory` table and alias of `i` Like `SELECT i.count FROM inventory i WHERE barcode = '123'`

Comment: yes, but this was just sample code, you are right but its still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this yet but it should get the job done.

In TSQL you would have the separation for `IF` and `IIF`, `IIF` being used in a `SELECT` statement only (acting the same as the `CASE` that you used) and `IF` being used as a standard IF (as in any other language). In MySQL these two are the same, simply `IF`(or in your example `CASE` within the `SELECT` statement), in this case  so in order to get the result that you want the following code should work:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE test() 
BEGIN
    IF 7 <= (SELECT i.count FROM inventory WHERE barcode = '123') THEN
        INSERT INTO transactions 
        (companyid,barcode,fromlocation,tolocation,count) 
        VALUES (1,'123','Warehouse','Factory',7);
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL test;
```

Comment: again it says for IF "Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 0)"

Comment: Okay so for some reason in MySQL you can only use `IF` statement inside a store procedure or a function, I am not sure why this it done this way, check the edit above .

Comment: The procedure needs to be created only ones, so after you run this code the first time (in case it gives you the error the first time just rename test to test_1 or something), you can just execute `CALL test` (or `CALL test_1`) to execute your code inside the procedure, hope that is clear enough.

Comment: oh ok, i didn't quite got the function of a procedure, now i understand, thank you very much